# Is there an idiomatic way to add an extension using Python's Pathlib?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pathlib

I'm using Python's Pathlib and I want to take something like

```
p = Path('/path/to/foo')
```

And then try a couple of different extensions. I can do

```
for ext in ['.txt', '.md', '.note']
    filename = Path(str(p) + ext)
```

but that feels a little awkward. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Maybe you could use endswith() but it doesn't feel awkward to me.

Comment: A format string could make this a little nicer: `filename = Path(f"{p}{ext}")`

Answer (score 121, accepted):

The [`with_suffix`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.with_suffix) method will return a new path with a different extension, either changing an existing extension or adding a new one. Examples from the docs:

```
>>> p = PureWindowsPath('c:/Downloads/pathlib.tar.gz')
>>> p.with_suffix('.bz2')
PureWindowsPath('c:/Downloads/pathlib.tar.bz2')
>>> p = PureWindowsPath('README')
>>> p.with_suffix('.txt')
PureWindowsPath('README.txt')
```

In your case, `p.with_suffix(ext)` would do the job.

For cases where you need to add a suffix after any existing suffixes instead of removing existing suffixes, you can use `p.with_suffix(p.suffix+ext)`. This is kind of clunky, though, and I don't know whether I would prefer it over `Path(str(p)+ext)`.

Comment: that's exactly what I wanted - it even replaces the suffix in the case of `foo.txt`, if I do `with_suffix('.md')` then it returns `foo.md`. Excellent! (also I was searching for "ext" or "extension" on the page, which apparently is why I missed that)

Comment: Nice, but what if you don't want to replace the existing suffix. Back to Path(str(path) + ".xyz")?

Comment: @MathieuLongtin: That, or `p.with_suffix(p.suffix+'.xyz')`.

Comment: That is better! Not great, but better.

Comment: I find `Path(f'{p}.xyz')` to be slightly better.

Comment: The fact that this replaces an existing suffix may mess up your filename, if it happens to contain a dot. E.g. `Path('07. Bats in the Belfry').with_suffix('.flac')` yields `07.flac`, which may be surprising and undesired.

Answer (score 16):

You might use pathlib3x - it offers a backport of the latest (at the date of writing this answer Python 3.10.a0) Python pathlib for Python 3.6 or newer, and a few additional functions like `append_suffix`

```
>>> python -m pip install pathlib3x

>>> import pathlib3x as pathlib

>>> pathlib.Path('some_path').append_suffix('.ext')
PosixPath('some_path.ext')

>>> pathlib.Path('some_path.ext.ext2').append_suffix('.ext3')
PosixPath('some_path.ext.ext2.ext3')

>>> pathlib.Path('some_path.ext').append_suffix('.tar.gz')
PosixPath('some_path.ext.tar.gz')
```

you can find it on [github](https://github.com/bitranox/pathlib3x) or [PyPi](https://pypi.org/project/pathlib3x)

---

<sup>Disclaimer: I'm the author of the pathlib3x library.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to `Path(str(p) + ext)` is

```
p.parent / (p.name + ext)
```

which arguably conveys the intention better.